# Problems Changing Background Color in PrimeFaces Tabs Component

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, tabs

I use [Primefaces 2.1](http://www.primefaces.org/)

I reference the css files like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url("resources/css/skin.css");
  @import url("resources/css/style.css");
</style>
```

In style.css I try to change the background color of the container in which the tabs are:

```
 .ui-tabs-nav{
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

This doesn't work. The change of the main tab container "works":

```
.ui-tabs{
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Not everyone knows what Primefaces is, a link to its resources would be a great help to help you.

Comment: check with Firebug the css, maybe there is some override...

Answer (score 0):

The pimefaces page on themes:
http://primefaces.org/themes.html

Scroll down to "Installing Themes"

You'll use the jQuery theme roller http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ to build a theme.  It's really easy and quick to do.  There are also a large number of prepackaged themes available.